# Azure AD 401 error - Authenticating from angular client

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, azure, azure-active-directory

I have a separate angular client that I want to authenticate to using Azure AD. I am using [ADAL JS](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) and all of that seems to be working fine. I get redirected to the AD login page, and then sent back to my application. I can see the token getting passed with each subsequent http request.

However, when I try to make a secured request to my Web API I receive a 401 Unauthorized error. I am loosely following the guide [here](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/04/28/use-owin-azure-ad-to-secure-both-mvc-ux-and-web-api-in-the-same-project/) for setup. I say loosely because I'm not using MVC, my client is in a separate codebase entirely.

I am positive that my user has access to this application.

My Auth Configuration stuff looks like:

```
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions()
{
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureADAudience"],
    },
    Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureADTenant"],
    AuthenticationType = "OAuth2Bearer"
});
```

Audience: `https://login.windows.net/xyz.onmicrosoft.com/myappname`

Tenant: `xyz.onmicrosoft.com`

The controller I'm locking down is decorated like this:

```
[HostAuthentication("OAuth2Bearer")]
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("Auth")]
```

Answer (score 2):

Is your SPA hosted with your backend? If so, then you need to change your audience to the Client ID.

```
ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientID"]
```